# Zariski-closure of finite linear groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, zariski-topology

I have come across the following Proposition from Milne:

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group over a field $k$ and $S$ a closed subgroup of $G(k)$. There is a unique algebraic subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $S=H(k)$ and $H$ ist geometrically reduced. The algebraic subgroups $H$ of $G$ that arise in this way are exactly those for which $H(k)$ is schematically dense in $H$.

So I am wondering what this means for subgroups of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$. I have read, that in the setting of finite linear groups, this Zariski-closure is always trivial. What does that precisely mean?

Thanks in advance for explanations.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "trivial", it's not a great idea to use this ambiguous word. In the case of a finite field, every subgroup is Zariski-closed. Now, I'm puzzled by the statement of uniqueness. Indeed, for $S=\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$, both the $n^2$-dimensional $H=\mathrm{GL}_n$ and the $0$-dimensional $H=\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$ seem to work. Maybe you're omitting the requirement that $H(k)$ should be dense in $H$ in the uniqueness statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The word “trivial” is what irritates me too. We have that, $H(k)$ is schematically dense in $H$ if and only if $H$ is geometrically reduced and $H(k)$ is dense in $H$, so we do have the requirement. So am I understanding it correctly, that for a subgroup $H\subseteq \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ the theorem would just return the subgroup itself?

Comment: Yes, I think so (it returns the finite subgroup itself).